# Exclude a list of filenames while removing files

Tags: bash, grep, rm

I want to remove all the files under directory `assets/img/fly` that are not needed in `_posts/2020-10-05-most-beautiful-story-i-ve-ever-heard.markdown`. These are the files to be excluded:

```
± |master → origin U:1 ✗| → grep '.jpg' _posts/2020-10-05-most-beautiful-story-i-ve-ever-heard.markdown 
![](/assets/img/fly/UEGDXB3U.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/YB59X0IS.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/8FBFIDB3.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/CGMZAZU6.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/HNW7TV6D.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/UZRLR5TE.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/F6RZHWOD.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/LEDROO88.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/4LOGZOM0.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/OFGII4Z3.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/IGTJ2LYH.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/UOM780JG.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/WY28RY5O.jpg)
![](/assets/img/fly/TVDZMBDI.jpg)
```

And these are the total files in the directory:

```
± |master → origin U:1 ✗| → ls assets/img/fly
4LOGZOM0.jpg CGMZAZU6.jpg HNW7TV6D.jpg LEDROO88.jpg OFGII4Z3.jpg TVDZMBDI.jpg UOM780JG.jpg WY28RY5O.jpg YB59X0IS.jpg
8FBFIDB3.jpg F6RZHWOD.jpg IGTJ2LYH.jpg LVPJ7B4F.jpg RDO3AY0Z.jpg UEGDXB3U.jpg UZRLR5TE.jpg XISY5DZD.jpg YIXITHTJ.jpg
```

I guess the procedure can be like extract the file names from output `grep` command and then compare with the output of `ls`. The exact command is tricky for me now.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: @unxnut I just edit it again.

Comment: So, you want to remove the files that show up in the output of `grep`?

Comment: @unxnut on the contrary, I want to remove all the files that don't show up in the output of grep

Comment: @thanasisp not exactly, I need to extract all the specific files at first. I didn't make it so far.

Comment: @thanasisp thanks for you help.  `find . -type f ! -name '*.jpg'` is not what I'm looking for, `find . -type f ! -name '*.jpg'` filter out all the files that do not end with `.jpg`. my problem is I have a `markdown` file, which has a dependency with files under directory `assets/img/fly`, there also other files that are redundant which has no use. I need to remove these irrelavant files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
d="assets/img/fly"
f="_posts/2020-10-05-most-beautiful-story-i-ve-ever-heard.markdown"
 
find "$d" -type f -print0 | 
    grep -vzf <(grep -o "assets.*jpg" "$f") | xargs -0 echo rm --
```

Remove `echo` if you are ok with testing. Also you may need to adjust the path of the markdown file relative to where you execute it.

`find` will get all files of your directory, `-print0` will pass the arguments to next command zero separated, preserving filenames.

`-z` flag makes `grep` to filter these arguments as zero separated and not by newlines. `-f` will look for the patterns of the first file into the arguments, and `-v` will exclude the matching arguments.

The file with the patterns is replaced with a process substitution running `grep -o` and returning the whole filename of the files to exclude. Also `xargs -0` treats the arguments as zero separated.

---

Here is a version without preserving the filenames, assuming all your files are like in the example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
d="assets/img/fly"
f="_posts/2020-10-05-most-beautiful-story-i-ve-ever-heard.markdown"
 
find "$d" -type f | grep -vf <(grep -o "assets.*jpg" "$f") | xargs echo rm --
```

Note: macOS GNU grep does not support `-z` option.